# django: Why do we use a nested meta class inside modelSerializer?

Tags: django, django-models, metaclass, django-serializer

I am new to python as well as to django and learning about serializers. I observed that While defining a serializer class it needs a nested meta class inside it. I am not good with this meta class concept, so i googled about it and found that metaclass is a class whose instances are classes. Even after reading that i am confused. Is the outer serializer class an instance of the inner meta class here? What is the need of using this meta class here?

Comment: No, that is a completely different concept. Here it's just an inner class with some definitions. But the same concept is used throughout Django; really, before you learn django-rest-framework, you should learn Django. If you had, this pattern wouldn't surprise you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python's metaclasses and Django's Meta classes are different concepts.

What you found on google is talking about Python's **metaclasses**, a construct that the Django framework uses a lot, but not in its user-facing code. [This blog post](http://blog.idego.pl/2015/02/10/how-django-uses-metaclasses/) goes into explaining how Django uses metaclasses in the framework's code.

Django's **Meta** classes on the other hand, it's an internal class structure used in some of the framework frontmost elements: Models, Forms, Serializers, ModelAdmins, etc. Those classes describe the configuration of a certain element that are read on runtime, or migration-time, but are not strictly saved on the database, because they're not of the database concern. For example, the framework reads the Meta configuration of a model when it needs to know what is the preferred order of a QuerySet of such model if order is not specified. Forms will read what fields it must validate when it calls `is_valid`. Et cetera.